# Trying to understand clojure Fibonacci recursion

Tags: recursion, clojure

I am trying to understand the below program to find the Fibonacci series using recursion in Clojure.

```
(defn fib
[x] 
(loop [i '(1 0)]
    (println i)
    (if (= x (count i))
        (reverse i)
        (recur 
          (conj i (apply + (take 2 i))))))) // This line is not clear
```

For ex for a call `fib(4)` I get the below output,

```
(1 0)
(1 1 0)
(2 1 1 0)
(0 1 1 2)
```

Which as per my inference the `conj` seems to add the value of `(apply + (take 2 i))` to the start of the `i`. But that is not the behaviour of `conj`. Can someone help me understand how exactly this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That *is* the behavior of `conj`, for *lists*. `conj` doesn't always add to the end:

```
(conj '(1) 2) ; '(2 1)

(conj [1] 2) ; [1 2]
```

The placement of the added element depends on the type of the collection. Since adding to the end of a list is expensive, `conj` adds to to front instead. It's the same operation (adding to a list), but optimized for the collection being used.

Answer (score 1):

Per Clojure documentation:

> The 'addition' may happen at different 'places' depending on the concrete type.

Appending to list happens to beginning of list, appending to vector happens to the end...

See more examples at https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj